# Can Node.js handle massive online judge webste?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am planing to develop something close to UVA and Code force online judge with my teammates in my University as a senior project. The system will be somehow huge because it has data mining, files, contests and more.
My main question is can Node.js be stable enough to handle this work ? or should I use PHP or ASP.net.
I read a sentence that said "It is not advisable to use Node.js for CPU intensive applications."
Sorry for the prolongation.

Comment: node is event driven, so use callbacks for intensive computations.

Comment: @naomik thanks for replay. But I don't think that this is a bad question. Imagine you have about 100 contests at the same time, so can one thread handle all the pressure? And as I read in an article, It is not advisable to use Node.js for CPU intensive applications. So i need an explanation for last sentence.

Comment: @alloush, you misunderstand how node operates.

Comment: @naomik yes agree with you

Comment: node code will be as fast as php or asp.net code, but most CPU-intensive operations are out of band of the single thread anyway, so they don't count against it. Busy background process use what CPU they need, but while they are busy node itself not doing anything. 100 clients is trivial for node. i think the article just means that it's better to use ffmpeg as a command-line node child-process than to load up an ASM-based export of ffmpeg and do video encoding in node's single thread.

Comment: @dandavis now I got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node.js handles Walmart's backend on Black Friday, I think it can handle your needs...

https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=6868363

Comment: to be fair, when i heard about that a few years ago, they had only handled half the black friday traffic with node... still impressive though.